# Could a planet's Karman line hypothetically occur under a liquid surface?

Tags: physics, hard-science, orbital-mechanics

The [Karman Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) is one of the most commonly-used definitions of the "edge of space".  As an airplane flies higher in the atmosphere, the air gets thinner and thus the lift decreases.  This can be compensated by flying at a faster speed.  The Karman line is the altitude at which you would need as much speed as the orbital velocity.  You are no longer flying; you are in orbit.

Earth has a gaseous atmosphere, and a Karman line that calculates to about 100 km.

[This Space.SE question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29910) examines the Karman line of a planet without an atmosphere (i.e. a solid surface).  The general consensus of the answers is that the solid surface itself is the "edge of space".  The moon is such a body.

So we have...

- the edge of space with a **solid** surface (moon).
- the edge of space with a **gaseous** atmosphere (Earth).

What about a planet (or moon) with a **liquid** surface -- namely, *could there be any contrived, theoretical scenario where the Karman line occurs **below** sea level*?

The oceans do not necessarily have to be water (e.g. ammonia, mercury, or hydrocarbons are fine).  You may adjust temperature, pressure, and gravity to any plausible values that support liquid oceans.  Presumably, to keep the oceans from boiling away, there would need to be a solid crust above the ocean, or some atmosphere inadequate for flight (your choice).

Interestingly, such a possibility would mean that no creature or vehicle could "swim" to the surface of their ocean.

Obviously, Earth itself proves you can have a Karman line *above* a liquid sea level.

Comment: Don't accept right off the bat! It is good practice to leave questions open for at least 24 hours to see if other answers appear.

Comment: Just an FYI: if you want the hard-science notice to go along with the tag, flag it for mod attention and they'll add the post notice. Just flagged accordingly (further info on that can be found in the [tag:hard-science] tag wiki.)

Comment: Water will sublimate in a vacuum. I followed [this reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/2cj79d/are_there_any_liquids_which_do_not_evaporate_in/) and found [this wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_liquid) about Ionic Liquids. They are salts in liquid form and do not evaporate/sublimate in a vacuum like water does.

Comment: @JohnLocke: Water ice will sublimate in air at normal pressure, not only in a vacuum. In vacuum liquid water will boil . . .

Comment: @AlexP The karman line is where the medium is so thin that orbital mechanics is holding you up more than aero/hydrodynamics. Therefore, the karman line is at least as tall as the highest point where matter is found in a relevant density, meaning if the planet has an atmosphere, the karman line will be at the top of the atmosphere, not, as the OP asked, under water, nor anywhere near the surface, it will end way above water. So if you have no atmosphere, you need something that will not sublimate.

Comment: AFIAK all subsurface water craft operate at very close to neutral buoyancy, lift is only used for maneuvering.  Thus the whole concept of the Karman line makes no sense.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## No

As long as you are in a liquid, the density will be high enough that an airfoil shape will be able to give you lift. In that case, you can always get to the surface of the liquid, with a sub-orbital velocity. Therefore, the Karman line can't be below the surface of the liquid.

#### Definition of the Karman line

The Karman line's [mathematical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line#Definition) is

$$\frac{1}{2}\rho v_0^2SC_L = mg$$

where $v_0$ is the orbital velocity; $m$ and $S$ are mass and wing area; and $C_L$ is coefficient of lift. The [wing loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing_loading) of an airplane is $m/S$ and is around 600 kg/m$^2$ for a commercial airplane. Via [Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9682/where-can-i-find-data-tables-for-lift-and-drag-coefficients-of-airliners) we can get [lift coefficients](https://aeroknowledge77.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/58986488-theory-of-wing-sections-including-a-summary-of-airfoil-data.pdf). Lift varies based on angle of attack, but $C_L=1$ is a good enough approximation. We can plug this into the equation to get:

$$ \frac{1}{1200}\rho v_0 = g.$$

So now we have a relationship between orbital velocity, gravity, and fluid density. Given a fluid density of water at 1000 kg/m$^3$, the surface gravity must be 0.83 times the orbital velocity, in units of m/s$^2$ and m/s, respectively, for a the Karman line to be below the liquid level.

#### Relationship between escape velocity and surface gravity

Now, escape velocity is not the same as orbital velocity, but it can give us an approximation of what orbital velocity is. LEO on Earth is ~7 km/s while escape velocity is 11.2 km/s. This will be close enough an approximation, as we will see.

Escape velocity can be expressed as a product of surface gravity by

$$v_0 = \sqrt{2gr}$$. We will use escape velocity as a stand-in for orbital velocity. Combine this equation with $g = 0.83 v_0$ and we get $v_0 = 1.7 r$, with units of m/s and m.

If escape velocity is the same as Earth, then the planet needs to be 19,000 km in radius (Earth is 6370) with surface gravity of 9260 $g$. If the planet is to have surface gravity of 9.8 m/s$^2$, then the escape velocity of this 'planet' is 12 m/s and its radius is 20 meters.

#### Calculation of required mass

So here you can see the impossibility forming. Escape velocity is

$$ v_e = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}.$$ If we plug in 12  m/s and a radius of 20 meters, we get a mass of $2.2\times10^{13}$ kg; this is a density of $4.4\times10^{8}$ kg/m$^3$ which is electron-degenerate matter.

## Conclusion

The only way to make this happen is to put a liquid ocean over a small asteroid's worth of electron degenerate matter. So, no, this cannot happen.

Comment: And I don't dare imagining what happens upon reaching orbital velocity into a liquid...

Comment: It would be brief, but exciting.

Comment: @DrSheldon, if you are in a liquid, you are, by definition, in a material of less density than if that same liquid was a gas. Thus, you don't even need an airfoil to reach the surface. You can theoretically use that same liquid in gaseous form to float to the surface, ie needing a horizontal speed of 0.

Comment: @KeithMorrison A rocket doesn't need a horizontal speed to get to the top of the atmosphere either, and it isn't in a liquid.

Comment: @JohnLocke Yes but it also will have a vertical speed of close to zero as well, and rockets can't do that.

Comment: @fyrepenguin Why can't you regulate how fast the rocket burns fuel to give it a vertical speed near zero? Is it because the rocket will be unstable?

Comment: Not to mention the fact that without enough preasure, the liquid becomes a gas. And the preasure is generally caused by the weight of the gaseous atmosphere pressing down on the liquid

Comment: @KeithMorrison That same though applies to a baloon filled with vacuum. The Karman line is determined with respect to an airfoil, so what can or cannot float is irrelevant.

Comment: @fyrepenguin The Apollo lunar module descent engine (not sure about the ascent stage) was able to maintain a vertical speed of zero during powered descent, if so desired by the astronauts (and Apollo 11 did nearly so late during the descent phase). I recall reading somewhere that one way to look at [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse) in seconds is that it's the amount of time a rocket could theoretically support itself in a hover before running out of fuel. Can't find a ready citation for that one right now, though.

Comment: @JohnLocke I will partially retract my statement.  Rockets can and will achieve zero vertical velocity, but that's usually outside the norm.  I had forgotten about SpaceX's booster landings which ended up being stationary momentarily. I will put forth the fact that a balloon or anything floating will be able to do so without constant energy expenditure, unlike a rocket.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I believe you are correct about that, and I will admit that I failed to qualify my original statement with the addition that a balloon would not require additional energy expenditure to maintain its stationary position.

Comment: @fyrepenguin Ok, I guess I just did not quite understand your comment. Just to point out one other thing- if you are turning a liquid into a gas, you will need some sort of energy expenditure, whether it is one big use at the start or a steady use the entire time.

Comment: @JohnLocke Yeah, that was my bad. Though you can have some sort of ground station do the energy expenditure for you, rather than carry it with you.

Comment: @fyrepenguin You're right, hadn't thought about that.